# Input int to file direction

Tags: c, int, fopen

I'm stuck trying to get a int into a file url in c programming. I googled and found nothing.

This is the code that works.

```
write=fopen("/Users/Funktiona/Desktop/data/data.txt", "w");
```

This is what I was thinking but it does not work

```
int i = 1;
write=fopen("/Users/Funktiona/Desktop/data/data%i.txt", "w", i);
```

Comment: Look at [`sprintf`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_sprintf.htm)

Comment: Use `fprintf` E.g. `fprintf(write, "%d", i)`

Answer (score 2):

You need:

```
#define FILENAME_LENGTH 200 /* Make it as large as you need to */

char filename[FILENAME_LENGTH];
sprintf(filename, "/Users/Funktiona/Desktop/data/data%i.txt", i);
write=fopen(filename, "w");
```

If you have access to a C99 or C++11 compiler, you should prefer `snprintf` to `sprintf`. `snprintf` is a safer option to prevent buffer overflows.

```
snprintf(filename, FILENAME_LENGTH, "/Users/Funktiona/Desktop/data/data%i.txt", i);
```

Checkout a [basic tutorial on basic IO in C](http://randu.org/tutorials/c/io.php).

Comment: You didn't answer his question. He wants to use a printf format string to create the **file name**.

Comment: @DoxyLover, I misunderstood the question the first time around. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Suggest `snprintf`  -- although your version works in this case, more generally using snprintf helps to prevent buffer overflows

Answer (score 0):

Only a few specific library functions do substitution into format strings, mainly the `printf` family. Calls such as `fopen` do not. You will need to create a string using `sprintf` or such and feed that string into `fopen`.

```
char filename[256];

snprintf(filename, sizeof filename, "/Users/Funktiona/Desktop/data/data%i.txt", x);
write = fopen(filename, "w");
```